# Oozie is not starting

Tags: hadoop, oozie, job-scheduling

I am using oozie 4.1.0 with CDH-5.5.1. I was enabling sla as answer to [this question](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Why-is-my-oozie-workflow-SLA-tab-blank/td-p/9416).

I removed all the FQCNs from **oozie.services.ext** property. It is using  PostgreSQL in the back end. I dont have any credentials of it.

It started throwing exception as follows

```
2016-05-03 09:31:28,312 FATAL org.apache.oozie.service.Services: SERVER[data4] Runtime Exception during Services Load. Check your list of 'oozie.services' or 'oozie.services.ext'
2016-05-03 09:31:28,321 FATAL org.apache.oozie.service.Services: SERVER[data4] E0103: Could not load service classes, Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "oozie_oozie_server")
org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0103: Could not load service classes, Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "oozie_oozie_server")
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:309)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.init(Services.java:213)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "oozie_oozie_server")
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:603)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1518)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:531)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:456)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:120)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:967)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:958)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:644)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.getEntityManager(JPAService.java:500)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.init(JPAService.java:201)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:386)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setService(Services.java:372)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:305)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "oozie_oozie_server")
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:91)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "oozie_oozie_server"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: Were you able to successfully use Oozie's SLA feature? If yes, can you please help answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281650/oozie-not-sending-sla-email-alerts

Answer (score 1):

You can check once in the catalina.log in /var/log/oozie/ directory, if there is any error.

Apart from that, hope, you didn't change the DB settings for Oozie manually.

You can verify it in [Oozie default Configuration](http://demo.gethue.com/oozie/list_oozie_info/) post.

Otherwise, you can re-create the Oozie service and launch.